# Why doesn't ESD cause a large amount of current?

Tags: esd

It is agreed that ESD is caused by kV level large potential differences:

[image]

When we handle an ESD sensitive device such as a MOSFET or a type of diode etc., why doesn't it burn when it gets damaged by the ESD? If V = I * Z , wouldn't kV level of voltage cause a huge current through the device? I am looking for an answer as a simple circuit model or a model equation which shows why we don't experience a huge amount of current.

Comment: You might have to wait for a while because we do get a large (up to several tens of amps) surge of current but, it totally depends on the series impedance of the whole circuit just as it does for any other circuit. This is why we use ESD prevention methods such as wrist straps and bench mats and anti-static bags.

Comment: Im looking for an answer with an R C circuit model or similar where shows extremely large ESD voltage but not huge currents.

Comment: Can we say the capacitor in the model doesn't let current to go so high? http://jds.elfak.ni.ac.rs/ssss2010/proceedings/proceedings%20files/separated%20chapters/02%20Simulating%20Electrostatic%20Discharge.pdf

Comment: @user1245 I would expect it's mostly the parasitic inductance. That limits how fast the current can rise. Add that to the capacitance limiting how long the current can last, and you have a pretty concrete limit on peak current. .

Comment: FYI, your question has likely been downvoted because you have phrased it to make assertions ("doesn't cause large current" "doesn't burn"), leaving answers no recourse but to directly contradict you (which isn't likely to result in effective learning) or tiptoe around those assertions (e.g. you didn't say over what time scale you meant for "large current"). If you rephrase this more openly (and hopefully, reframe your own perspective), to ask what happens and how/why, rather than to presume and contradict -- you will find answers come much more easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model most found to be useful is a 1.5kΩ resistor and a 100pF capacitor charged to a high voltage. It is described, for example, in [MIL-STD 883](http://everyspec.com/MIL-STD/MIL-STD-0800-0899/download.php?spec=MIL_STD_883F.270.pdf):

[image]

A suggested schematic is provided in the linked standard.

Whether an ampere or so is a "huge" current is a matter of perspective. It's pretty large for a small structure on an IC to absorb, particularly if there is much voltage across the structure.

Answer (score 3):

ESD does cause huge currents to flow, but only for a very brief time. They can severely damage semiconductors and there is certainly enough energy to make a visible flash as air is ionized. However, the damage only occurs over a very tiny area. Which is often quite large compared to the silicon die.
[A desription of ESD damage and mechanism from which the photo is taken](https://www.integrasources.com/blog/electronics-design-practices-prevent-eos-and-esd-damage/)

[image]

Comment: Can we say the capacitor in the model doesn't let current to go so high? http://jds.elfak.ni.ac.rs/ssss2010/proceedings/proceedings%20files/separated%20chapters/02%20Simulating%20Electrostatic%20Discharge.pdf

Comment: @user1245 Capacitors, at least the ideal sort used in models, do not limit current at all; an ideal capacitor would have infinite current (for an infinitesimal time) when shorted.

Answer (score 0):

Bits of the sensitive parts *do* burn up.  It's just that ESD is driven by huge voltage (relative to the part's ratings) stored in a very small capacitor.

So the *total energy* stored isn't enough to cause visible damage to the bulk of the part.  However, it's more than enough to cause places in the interior of the part to get damaged.

The damage usually isn't visible, and often it doesn't cause a total or immediate failure of the part -- this means that you can have a damaged component that doesn't work quite right, or that fails later on, in the field.

Answer (score 0):

> V = I * Z , wouldn't kV level of voltage cause a huge current through the device?

This assumes infinite power or infinite charge. In other words, it assumes that the voltage level can be maintained even as current starts to flow, and can be maintained for a "long" period of time. The capacitance of objects storing the charge to shock things is very tiny so there isn't enough charge or power to keep it going. So in reality that small amount of very high voltage charge gets loaded down very quickly once current starts to flow.

It's the difference between a tiny drop of water at 90C hitting your skin versus a potful of 90C water hitting your skin. The tiny drop of hot water isn't going to burn you because there's not enough power behind it to maintain the hot temperature when it makes contact with you.

> I am looking for an answer as a simple circuit model or a model equation which shows why we don't experience a huge amount of current.

You don't need a circuit model to explain it. It's just the progression between something like a power plant->generator->large battery->small battery->large capacitor->small capacitor if they all had the same voltage. The model literally is just a ~10pF capacitor (for the human body model) versus the infinite capacitor that you are imagining.